# What’s the meaning of RPM jump from 3,4 while traveling 25mph? And sounds like it’s at higher idle?

Tags: chevrolet, idle, rpm

SUV - Chevrolet Equinox Sports 2009

Answer (score 1):

Is your vehicle downshifting perhaps?  That would explain the higher revs.  It's not "idle" if it's in gear and you are driving, BTW.

You might want to clarify what you mean by "3,4" - is that from 3000 RPM to 4000 RPM?

Comment: I would expect that the tach in that vehicle is marked in single digits and the operator is unaware of the x1000 legend below the center, if it is there.